# Undefined property: stdClass::$cookie

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

How do I resolve this error?

> /var/www/html/cy_prestashop/modules/taxcloud/**taxcloud.php**: 1178",
>
> "(Notice) Undefined property: **stdClass::$cookie**"

Comment: That error message is already very helpful to you, have you viewed the prestashop documentation?

Comment: Cleaned up the title since pretashop is already a tag, and formatted the error to be easier to read.

Comment: You should use the context not the $cookie variable directly i don't know if calling global $cookie will fix rhe problem

Answer (score 0):

`Notice` are not errors that stop the normal shop function. You can see it because you have active Prestashop DEBUG MODE.

Anyway, the problem is a bad programming of your module `taxcloud` located in line 1178 as your error said. You must look for a developer help if this problem affect your shop behavior.

Good luck.